# How to I use reduce() to console.log on each iteration?

Tags: javascript, loops, reduce

JavaScript

I have the solution below working properly but would like to do it with the reduce method. How would I go about doing that?

```
function main(arr) {
    let max = arr[0];
    arr.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (value >= max) {
            max = arr[index]
            console.log(max);
        }
    })
}

main([1,  3,  8,  4,  10,  12,  3,  2,  24]);
```

Expected Result (each number on a separate line) :
1
3
8
10
12
24

Comment: Are you working in javascript? what did you try with the reduce method and what error did you get?

Comment: I don't understand how you get that output from that input. Or why you're using forEach and accessing the array through the index. Is this the actual code?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the proper inputs. Yes it is JavaScript. When I try to replicate this with reduce, nothing prints to the console.

Comment: I don't think reduce does what you think it does. Why are you focussed on reduce in particular? Might want to be more open to hearing about ways to do this.

Comment: I do not normally use reduce this way. I was asked if it could be used this way. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the reduce method

```js
[1,  3,  8,  4,  10,  12,  3,  2,  24].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (acc < cur) {
    console.log(cur)
    acc = cur
  }
  return acc
}, 0)
```